# Error pip install web3 on windows even after installing microsoft build tools

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pip, web3py

I am new to python and i have have been trying to install web3 for some days even after installing microsoft build tools and checkmarking all the neccessities like windows 10sdk and all c++ build tools.But i'm still getting this error.I have googled this problem but still no solution,leaving me stuck at this step and its really frustrating , i even restarted my system after installing the microsoft build tools and yet i am still getting the error below.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools>py -m pip install web3
Collecting web3
  Using cached web3-5.28.0-py3-none-any.whl (499 kB)
Collecting aiohttp<4,>=3.7.4.post0
  Using cached aiohttp-3.8.1-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl (555 kB)
Collecting eth-abi<3.0.0,>=2.0.0b6
  Using cached eth_abi-2.1.1-py3-none-any.whl (27 kB)
Collecting hexbytes<1.0.0,>=0.1.0
  Using cached hexbytes-0.2.2-py3-none-any.whl (6.1 kB)
Collecting ipfshttpclient==0.8.0a2
  Using cached ipfshttpclient-0.8.0a2-py3-none-any.whl (82 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: pywin32>=223 in c:\users\kadit cuy\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from web3) (303)
Collecting protobuf<4,>=3.10.0
  Using cached protobuf-3.19.4-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl (895 kB)
Collecting eth-account<0.6.0,>=0.5.7
  Using cached eth_account-0.5.7-py3-none-any.whl (101 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: eth-typing<3.0.0,>=2.0.0 in c:\users\kadit cuy\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from web3) (2.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: eth-hash[pycryptodome]<1.0.0,>=0.2.0 in c:\users\kadit cuy\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from web3) (0.3.2)
Collecting lru-dict<2.0.0,>=1.1.6
  Using cached lru-dict-1.1.7.tar.gz (10 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Collecting eth-utils<2.0.0,>=1.9.5
  Using cached eth_utils-1.10.0-py3-none-any.whl (24 kB)
Collecting websockets<10,>=9.1
  Using cached websockets-9.1.tar.gz (76 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Collecting jsonschema<4.0.0,>=3.2.0
  Using cached jsonschema-3.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (56 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: requests<3.0.0,>=2.16.0 in c:\users\kadit cuy\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from web3) (2.27.1)
Collecting multiaddr>=0.0.7
  Using cached multiaddr-0.0.9-py2.py3-none-any.whl (16 kB)
Collecting attrs>=17.3.0
  Using cached attrs-21.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (60 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: charset-normalizer<3.0,>=2.0 in c:\users\kadit cuy\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from aiohttp<4,>=3.7.4.post0->web3) (2.0.12)
Collecting aiosignal>=1.1.2
  Using cached aiosignal-1.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (8.2 kB)
Collecting yarl<2.0,>=1.0
  Using cached yarl-1.7.2-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl (122 kB)
Collecting frozenlist>=1.1.1
  Using cached frozenlist-1.3.0-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl (33 kB)
Collecting multidict<7.0,>=4.5
  Using cached multidict-6.0.2-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl (27 kB)
Collecting async-timeout<5.0,>=4.0.0a3
  Using cached async_timeout-4.0.2-py3-none-any.whl (5.8 kB)
Collecting parsimonious<0.9.0,>=0.8.0
  Using cached parsimonious-0.8.1.tar.gz (45 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Collecting rlp<3,>=1.0.0
  Using cached rlp-2.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (20 kB)
Collecting bitarray<1.3.0,>=1.2.1
  Using cached bitarray-1.2.2.tar.gz (48 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Collecting eth-keys<0.4.0,>=0.3.4
  Using cached eth_keys-0.3.4-py3-none-any.whl (21 kB)
Collecting eth-rlp<2,>=0.1.2
  Using cached eth_rlp-0.3.0-py3-none-any.whl (5.0 kB)
Collecting eth-keyfile<0.6.0,>=0.5.0
  Using cached eth_keyfile-0.5.1-py3-none-any.whl (8.3 kB)
Collecting pycryptodome<4,>=3.6.6
  Using cached pycryptodome-3.14.1-cp35-abi3-win_amd64.whl (1.8 MB)
Collecting cytoolz<1.0.0,>=0.10.1
  Using cached cytoolz-0.11.2.tar.gz (481 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in c:\users\kadit cuy\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from jsonschema<4.0.0,>=3.2.0->web3) (61.2.0)
Collecting six>=1.11.0
  Using cached six-1.16.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (11 kB)
Collecting pyrsistent>=0.14.0
  Using cached pyrsistent-0.18.1-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl (61 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.27,>=1.21.1 in c:\users\kadit cuy\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from requests<3.0.0,>=2.16.0->web3) (1.26.9)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<4,>=2.5 in c:\users\kadit cuy\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from requests<3.0.0,>=2.16.0->web3) (3.3)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in c:\users\kadit cuy\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from requests<3.0.0,>=2.16.0->web3) (2021.10.8)
Requirement already satisfied: toolz>=0.8.0 in c:\users\kadit cuy\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from cytoolz<1.0.0,>=0.10.1->eth-utils<2.0.0,>=1.9.5->web3) (0.11.2)
Collecting eth-rlp<2,>=0.1.2
  Using cached eth_rlp-0.2.1-py3-none-any.whl (5.0 kB)
Collecting base58
  Using cached base58-2.1.1-py3-none-any.whl (5.6 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: varint in c:\users\kadit cuy\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from multiaddr>=0.0.7->ipfshttpclient==0.8.0a2->web3) (1.0.2)
Requirement already satisfied: netaddr in c:\users\kadit cuy\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from multiaddr>=0.0.7->ipfshttpclient==0.8.0a2->web3) (0.8.0)
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for lru-dict, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for websockets, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for bitarray, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for cytoolz, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for parsimonious, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing collected packages: lru-dict, bitarray, websockets, six, pyrsistent, pycryptodome, protobuf, multidict, hexbytes, frozenlist, cytoolz, base58, attrs, async-timeout, yarl, parsimonious, multiaddr, jsonschema, eth-utils, aiosignal, rlp, ipfshttpclient, eth-keys, eth-abi, aiohttp, eth-rlp, eth-keyfile, eth-account, web3
  Running setup.py install for lru-dict ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Running setup.py install for lru-dict did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [7 lines of output]
      running install
      C:\Users\KADIT CUY\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
        warnings.warn(
      running build
      running build_ext
      building 'lru' extension
      error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> lru-dict

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.

Please someone should help!!
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to install the wheel first: `pip install wheel`. Then you can avoid using `setup.py install`.

And you can update the `Microsoft Visual C++` to 14 or greater like the error message suggestted.

Comment: `lru-dict` does [not have any whl files on pypi](https://pypi.org/project/lru-dict/#files)

Answer (score 0):

Sidenote: The error originates from installing `lru-dict`, not `web3` directly.

You seem to have visual studio 2022 installed. You should check that you have installed all optional features needed for compiling for python (from [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/WindowsCompilers)):

- Install the Python development workload and the optional Python native development tools option.
- Install the latest Windows SDK (under Native development in the installer).
- Optional: Set $env:PlatformToolset to your toolset version before building, if it doesn't detect it. (Alternatively, you could open the developer command prompt)
- Update to the latest setuptools Python package version

Especially the last is needed to have support for the latest compilers. Run `pip install --upgrade setuptools`. Then try to install again

Comment: I tried everything, including uninstalling and reinstalling pip, but it didn't work, so I'm now using wsl, which is working wonderfully so far. Thanks